# Horizontal form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to study rails with bootstrap.

I think simple form is very useful.

So, I wrote rails like this.

```
= simple_form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => {:action => 'serarch'}, :html => {:class => 'well'} do |f|
  = f.input :user_name
  = f.input :birth_day
```

It's pretty good.

But, I want to put these input forms horizontally on my browser.

How to do this ?

I don't want to use f.input_field.

input is useful than input_field, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use bootstrap's horizontal forms?

Add 'form-horizontal' to your html class, e.g.

```
= simple_form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => {:action => 'serarch'}, :html => {:class => 'well form-horizontal'} do |f|
  = f.input :user_name
  = f.input :birth_day
```